# Different registration page for different users

Tags: laravel

I used laravel framework to create a job portal and the web app will be used by the job seeker and the employer. How do i create a different registration page for those users?

Answer (score 0):

You can define different routes and views as per the user type.

For instance:

Job seeker registration route:

```php
Route::get('job-seeker/registration', function(){
  return view('job-seeker.registration');
});
```

Employer registration:

```php
Route::get('employer/registration', function(){
  return view('employer.registration');
});
```

And then you can customize views as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***`auth()->user->attribute`*** in order to return a different view if you want to discrimine the type of user by an attribute in the users table.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this in route page.

Route::get('/register/job','RegisterController@jobseeker');
Route::get('/register/employer','RegisterController@employer');